# Nuts and Bolts problem: Simpler $o(n^2)$ algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms

In [this paper](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/17.pdf), the authors mention that it is possible to get an $o(n^2)$-time algorithm for [the nuts and bolts problem](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PUZZLES/nuts_solution.html) by choosing samples based on a projective plane. They also mention that a non-constructive $O(n^{1.5}\log n)$-time algorithm can be obtained (pages 2-3). They omit the details.

I am interested in understanding these approaches, although they are not optimal. Could someone please provide the details of how this is done?

Comment: (1) Have you asked the authors?  (2) It's not clear that these algorithms are "easy"!

Comment: (1) Not yet. (2) I meant 'easier'..I've edited the question.